# ReactNative: How to Update ScrollView Content When New Data Is Received

Tags: react-native, horizontalscrollview

This may be a noob question but trust me, I've searched all over and for the life of me, I can't seem to be able to solve or find resources to fix this.

My issue is quite simple, I have a Button that, when pressed, opens an Image Picker from the device. I also have a ScrollView that, ideally, should contain all the Images I pick from the device.

So what I want to do is this: Pick an image and then display that Image on the ScrollView. The ScrollView itself can display Images ***as long as they are available on startup*** but I want to be able to add images as I pick them from the gallery.

I tried using a state object but, for whatever reason, the scrollview doesnt update.

Here Is The Relevant Picker Code:

```js
const addAsset = () => {
    const options = {
      title: title,
      customButtons: [],
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: '../../assets/imgs',
      },
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      // console.log('Response = ', response);
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        alert(response.customButton);
      } else {
        let oldSource = dataSource;
        // oldSource.push(response.uri)
        dataSource.push({
          id: 4,
          image: response.uri
        })
        // setDataSource(oldSource) //update state to update Image
        // console.log(dataSource)
      }
      });
    }
```

The Minimal ImageView object:

```js
const ImageView = (key, src) => {
    return (
      // Flat List Item
      <View key={src.id} style={{padding: 10}}>
        <Image source={src.image}/>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

And on the ScrollView, I tried:

```js
<ScrollView horizontal style={styles.assetsWrapper}>
    {dataSource.map(ItemView)}
</ScrollView>
```

And dataSource, for those wondering, looks like this:

```js
const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);
```

Comment: You have to update state in order to update scrollview with newest data source array.

Answer (score 0):

try this .. I kept it simple, you can change as requirement

...

```
else {
    let oldSource = [...dataSource];
    dataSource.push(image)
    setDataSource(oldSource) 
  }
```

//////////

```
<ScrollView horizontal style={styles.assetsWrapper}>
      {dataSource.map((item, index) => (
        <ImageView key={index} image={item} />
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
```

////////

```
const ImageView = ({image}) => {
    return (
      // Flat List Item
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <Image source={image}/>
      </View>
    );
  };
```